# Facebook Business Ads Python: An acces token different type permission

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-python-business-sdk

I have such problem:

> On my profile i have 4 account and i can use normally .create_custom_audience and .add_users on each of them.
>   But when i'm trying to get some stats by method .get_insights_async - it's working only on 3 of them.
>   For 1 that is not working it gives me error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104,
      "fbtrace_id": "AbNbFCGcLf7yCcEXTe8v_cW"
   }
}
```

How it can be possible? 
And how i can check various type permissions of my token for every account in GraphApi for example?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You need to show us what you are actually doing, otherwise this would all just be guesswork.

Comment: _“And how i can check various type permissions of my token for every account in GraphApi for example?”_ - token debug tool, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/